# Learning new declaration syntax JavaScript for arrays with :

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I'm learning **JavaScript** / **typescript** and i know that this is an array but it doesn't look like the standard declaration of an array.

I'm wondering what makes this unique to its purpose, its implementation  and where do I use it. Please help provide context to me as I don't understand this syntax. it is a loop? and what for?

```
var examples: example [] = [];
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is TypeScript (not JavaScript):

```
var examples: example[] = [];
```

It says that *examples* is an array of objects, each of type *example*, and is initialized to an empty array.

It's similar to the following where a is an array of numbers, initialized to contain 3 numbers (1, 2, 3):

```
var a: number[] = [1, 2, 3];
```